# How to reverse proxy two times with nginx?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have this configuration on nginx server_1:

```
upstream server_2 {
 server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
 listen 80;
 server_name *.mydomain.com;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 location / {
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_pass http://server_2;
 }
}
```

And this config on nginx server_2

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header Host $host;

server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name ~^subdomain\.mydomain\.com$;
    location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2000; }
}
```

Now redirects are not working, for example

if /url should be redirected to /otherurl and the request was http://subdomain.mydomain.com/url the redirect url returned to the browser is http://server_1/otherurl instead of http://subdomain.mydomain.com/otherurl

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290141/nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection).

Just remove `proxy_redirect off`, and add the following line to the location block

```
proxy_set_header HOST $host;
```

It will become

```
 location / {
   proxy_pass http://server_2;
   proxy_set_header HOST $host;
 }
```